# How can I standardize some SQL query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, standards

I've been working on some SQL query and it works well, but some full stack developer told me it isn't in the best practice, so he doesn't give me any feedback about how can I standardize this one!

This is my model function.

```
function getExternalSchools( $school_group_id ) {
$schools = DB::connection( 'sqlsrv' )
            ->table( 'T_CLIENTS AS cli' )
            ->join( 'T_SE AS e', 'e.idse', '=', 'cli.idse' )
            ->join( 'T_CITY AS cid', 'cid.cod_city', '=', 'cli.cod_city' )
            ->leftJoin( 'T_CLIENTS_SP AS csp', 'cli.cod_client', '=', 'csp.cod_client', 'AND', 'cli.idse','=','csp.idse' )
            ->leftJoin( 'T_CLIENT_CONTRACT AS cc', 'cc.cod_client', '=', 'cli.cod_client' )
                ->select(                    
                    'cli.cod_client',
                    'cli.Status',
                    'cli.IU'                 
                )
                ->whereRaw(implode(' ', [
                    "cli.category = 'C'",
                    "AND (cli.status = 'A' OR ISNULL(csp.cod_pae,0) <> 0)",
                    "AND cli.idse IN (1, 2, 10)",
                    "AND cli.FisJur = 'J'",
                    "AND cli.ERP_OK <> 0",
                    "AND cli.Typo = ''",
                    "AND cli.Status = 'A'",
                    "AND cli.school_group_id = '{$school_group_id}'",
                ]))
                ->get();

}
```

This function retrieves some schools from an external SQL SERVER database. So I only can read the data from this database.

Where can I improve this one?

Thank you

Comment: I guess he means this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes @Sunuba, but I'm reading this external database, should I abstract this tables to models inside my application? Did you got it?

Comment: Definitely got it. I think the same here, abstraction would be the way to go. Then create relations.

Comment: @Sunuba I mean "abstraction" not in literal mode, I mean to turn it in a Laravel model. But, these tables don't make part of my application, even so, I need to query this one because I wanna these external data. Got it?